# Typescript filter items in Angular FormsArray

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a child component that receives a form as an input

```
@Input() connectionForm: FormGroup;
```

on that form is a FormArray called connectionVases:

```
this.mobileConnectionForm = this.fb.group({
  ...
  connectionVases: this.fb.array([...this.createItems(this.connection.connectionVases)])
```

in the child component typescript file I have an accessor:

```
get BoltOns(){
  return this.connectionForm.get('connectionVases') as FormArray;
}
```

which I iterate over in the html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let bolt of BoltOns.controls; let i = index">
```

but I don't want to return all of the items. What is the best way to filter them? The array implements the interface:

```
export interface IConnectedVas {
  id: number,
  connectionId: number,
  vasesId: number,
  vasState: number
}
```

and I want to filter where the vasState property is equal to a specific value.

What do I need to add to the ngFor or can I do it in the getter in the typescript file?

Comment: You can use `*ngIf`, that's probably the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let bolt of BoltOns.controls; let i = index">
  <tr *ngIf="bolt.vasState == X">
  ...
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

You need the ng-container because you can't have `ngFor` and `ngIf` on the same element.

An alternative would be using a pipe on `BoltOns.controls`, but that would be overly complicated for your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this purpose you can use filter, your code will be like :

```
<tr *ngFor="let bolt of BoltOns.controls | filter : bolt.vasState : 'X'"; let i = index">
```

Pipe can will be like this:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], field : string, value): any[] {
      if (!items) return [];
      if (!value || value.length === 0) return items;
      return items.filter(it =>
      it[field] === value);
    }
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: Thanks for this. I was thinking of using a pipe, partly so I could learn a bit more about using them. Going to put the *ngIf solution in just because it's a bit simpler and cleaner. Appreciate your answer though. Going to give it a try so I can experiment with them a bit more